# Kotlin Spring Jdbc Cannot Use NULL

Tags: kotlin, spring-jdbc

I have the following method in a Spring Boot application using Kotlin. It won't compile because addValue method takes String paramName, and Object value. In my case passing NULL is a valid case, because I want all bankers, not ones from a specific branch.

Is there anyway to work around this in Kotlin.

```
override fun getBankers(branchId: UUID?): Iterable<Banker> {
    val query = this.sql.getProperty("banker.selectByBranch")
    val params = MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("branchId", null)
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, BankerRowMapper())
}
```

If I do branchId!! I get an NPE.

Comment: What error do you see actually? is passing null to addValue the problem?

Comment: Yea I can't pass null or a nullable type even

Answer (score 0):

If you call your method with a null `branchId` parameter and inside your method you use that parameter with the `!!` operator, you will get a NullPointerException because that's what the `!!` operator does. Shouldn't you use the parameter in your method somehow? Maybe like this:

```
override fun getBankers(branchId: UUID?): Iterable<Banker> {
    val query = this.sql.getProperty("banker.selectByBranch")
    val params = MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("branchId", branchId?.toString())
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, BankerRowMapper())
}
```

Comment: This does not compile because branchId?toString() returns String? and it is requiring a non nullable type.

Comment: @greyfox Try to use: `branchId?.toString() ?: ""` or `branchId ?: ""` The empty string in quote is the return value in case the left side of `?:` is null